# How to export R's RasterLayer to a 3D model?

Tags: r, r-raster

I have a RasterLayer I'm happy with, but I would like to export it as a 3D model. The contours are non-rectangular, so the upshot is the areas in the bounding box outside the contours are filled with NaN.

What is a good way to export this to some kind of 3D model?

P.S. I'm pretty open on the 3D model format, but ideally STEP file so it can be imported directly into standard CAD packages, such as OnShape.

Comment: package {rayshader} might be useful: https://www.rayshader.com/

Comment: yes rayshader has a function save_3dprint that creates a .stl file that can be used for printing or converting to a .stp file using autodesk

Comment: rayshader looks neat, but unfortunately seems to have problems on this computer (macOS 12.6, M2 chip).

Comment: `raster::rasterToPolygons()` could be a start point?